# Python fbchat Library Questions

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two main questions about the fbchat library. The first is hypothetical, and the second is code/function based.

My first question is can fbchat return when a user is online? When I use this code:

```
 persons = client.getUsers(name)
 for person in persons:
    person_info = client.getUserInfo(person.uid)
    if person_info['is_friend'] == True:
        print person_info
```

I get something like this (replaced all info with generic things out of respect for privacy):

```
{u'alternateName': u'', u'name': u'Name', u'firstName': u'Name', u'gender': 2, u'thumbSrc': u'url', u'uri': u'url', u'searchTokens': [u'Name', u'Name'], u'dir': None, u'is_friend': True, u'numbers/letters': number, u'mThumbSrcSmall': None, u'is_nonfriend_messenger_contact': False, u'type': u'friend', u'id': u'number', u'mThumbSrcLarge': None, u'vanity': u'messenger_id'}
```

I was wondering if one of these was a measure to see if the person was online, or how to do so.

Second question is about the reading of messages. Using this code, I get an error (pasted bellow the code).

```
def check_message():
    client = login()
    friend = "Name"

    last_messages = client.getThreadInfo(client.getUsers(friend)[0].uid, 0)
    last_messages.reverse()

    for message in last_messages:
        print(message.body)
```

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lukec/PycharmProjects/Sysgen_AI/test.py", line 32, in <module>
    check_message()
  File "C:/Users/lukec/PycharmProjects/Sysgen_AI/test.py", line 30, in check_message
    print(message.body)
AttributeError: Message instance has no attribute 'body'
```

But the [fb chat pypi page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fbchat/) says that message.body does exist...

Also, when I remove the .body at the end, I get this output instead:

```
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
<fbchat.models.Message instance at value>
```

Any idea why? I am building a personal bot/AI that covers a variety of tasks.

**Edit:** Using @fsociety's suggestion, dir(message) returns the following:

```
['__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', u'action_type', u'attachments', u'author', u'author_email', u'body', u'commerce_message_type', u'customizations', u'ephemeral_ttl_mode', u'folder', u'forward_count', u'forward_message_ids', u'has_attachment', u'is_filtered_content', u'is_filtered_content_account', u'is_filtered_content_bh', u'is_filtered_content_invalid_app', u'is_filtered_content_quasar', u'is_forward', u'is_sponsored', u'is_spoof_warning', u'is_unread', u'message_id', u'message_source', u'meta_ranges', u'montage_reply_data', u'offline_threading_id', u'other_user_fbid', u'platform_xmd', u'profile_ranges', u'ranges', u'raw_attachments', u'reactions', u'skip_bump_thread', u'source', u'source_tags', u'subject', u'tags', u'thread_fbid', u'thread_id', u'threading_id', u'timestamp', u'timestamp_absolute', u'timestamp_datetime', u'timestamp_relative', u'timestamp_time_passed']
```

As you can see "body" comes up. I'm now more confused on why the error occurs. Also, why is the first one (person_info) different from this one (message)? I'd expect it to be a dict as well (so a key can be called).

**Edit 2:** Using the following, I get an error:

```
def check_message():
    client = login()
    friend = "Name"

    last_messages = client.getThreadInfo(client.getUsers(friend)[0].uid, 0)
    last_messages.reverse()

    for message in last_messages:
        print(message['body'])
```

The error is:

```
 File "C:/Users/lukec/PycharmProjects/Sysgen_AI/test.py", line 33, in <module>
    check_message()
 File "C:/Users/lukec/PycharmProjects/Sysgen_AI/test.py", line 31, in check_message
    print(message['body'])
 AttributeError: Message instance has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Thoughts?

**Edit 3:** Printing other attributes of the message works, just not the body... for example, I can

```
print message.timestamp_datetime
```

and get:

```
October 10, 2016 7:16 pm
```

as output. Not sure if the message.body issue is me or the library then. Any workarounds you can think of?

Comment: Regarding the second part,please try dir(message) to confirm if body attribute actually exists

Comment: Thanks! What it returns has been edited up into the main post. "body" is something that is printed if I print dir(message). I never knew about the dir command. Very useful!

Comment: how about `print(message.body)` ?

Comment: @SancaKembang that is the problem I first got. Their pypi page says that's the way it should be done (message.body, not message['body']), but I get an attribute error from that, which is already posted above.

Comment: how about `message.body.encode('cp860', errors='ignore')`? -> to set chcp 65001 on windows to make cmd `utf-8` compatible.

Comment: May this script is usefull for you: https://github.com/Charliiee/fbchat-terminal/blob/master/fbchat-terminal/chat.py#L91

Comment: @SancaKembang using `message.body.encode('cp860' errors='ignore` still gives me the error that body doesn't exist... same thing if I copy the try/except Exception block: `try:
                    print("%s - %s" % (message.timestamp_datetime, message.body))
                except Exception:
                    # remember to set chcp 65001 on windows to make cmd utf8 compatible
                    print("%s - %s" % (message.timestamp_datetime,
                                       message.body.encode('cp860', errors='ignore')))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

When a friend finally joins Messenger, Facebook sends an alert to you stating so. fbchat sees this as a message and tries to cache and parse it, but gets tripped up on it not having a body.

Using this:

```
for Message in last_messages:
    message_time = Message.timestamp_datetime
        try:
            message_body = Message.body
            print message_time
            print message_body
        except:
            pass
```

It gets passed the issue of the first message not having a body and can go on to print subsequent messages.

Thanks so much for your help @SancaKembang. I wouldn't have figured it out if you'd never linked [this](https://github.com/Charliiee/fbchat-terminal/blob/master/fbchat-terminal/chat.py#L91). It got me to look into the library files themselves and see why the error was arising versus just looking at my code.